# Can't assign API data from fetch to variable in function

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, es6-modules

I have a JS module that is a function that fetches Issue data from our company Github, that I then want assigned to a variable:

```
import { request } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@octokit/request";

let issueData

async function getIssues() {
    const issueAPI = await request("GET repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues", {
        baseUrl: "https://company.com/api/v3/",
        owner: "me",
        repo: "exampleRepo",
    });

    window.issueData = issueAPI.data
    return issueAPI.data
}

export { getIssues, issueData }
```

I can't seem to get the `issueAPI.data` to assign to my variable `issueData`? What's going wrong here? I have a feeling it's something to do with the promises/async or scope but just can't work it out.

Comment: You don't need an external library for this. You can `await fetch(url, options)` directly.

Comment: Using the library for more than just this one function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `issueAPI.data` to a window variable called `issueData`, which is not the same variable that you have defined with `let` on your snippet. If you want to assign to your declared variable, you just need to do this.

```
let issueData = await getIssues()
```

If there are no other errors in the function, this should correctly assign what you want to your declared variable.

Also you can drop the `window.issueData = issueAPI.data` unless you really want to have that accesible from the window object.

EDIT: As Jeremy points out, this would require top-level await. A workaround also provided by Jeremy:

```
let issueData
( async () => { issueData = await getIssues() })()
```

Comment: Good answer, although it requires the ability to `await` at top-level (outside an `async` function), which is a recent feature (Node 14.3 I believe, I don't know about browsers)

Comment: So when I do that, I get the error "Unexpected reserved word"?!

Comment: That is probably related to Jeremy's comment. I added another solution.

Comment: @eloyra Your edit ruins your solution. Using `.then()` will cause the `export` to happen before `issueData` is defined. You must instead create a self-executing async function `let issueData; ( async () => { issueData = await getIssues() })();`

Comment: it seems top-level await is enroute to browsers, and can be enabled in chrome using `chrome.exe --js-flags="--harmony-top-level-await"`

Comment: @JeremyThille if you want to post that solution I can mark it as correct - it works.

Comment: @eloyra Feel free to edit your answer with my solution. Then OP can mark it as accepted. Team work :)

Comment: Thanks @JeremyThille I changed my answer